# Adobe AIR cacheAsBitmap and GPU rendering

Tags: caching, air, gpu

On page 68 of the Optimizing Flash guide 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/flashplatform_optimizing_content.pdf

it states that cacheAsBitmap must be enabled on displayObjects for GPU rendering to have any benefit.

Is this still the case with FP11 and when targeting mobile using AIR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, GPU rendering is helpful only on objects that cache a bitmap representation.

But, it's not that simple, you cannot just turn on cacheAsBitmap and cacheAsBitmapMatrix on everything and get a performance boost. Bitmap cacheing incurs a memory penalty (a major consideration on mobile), and for objects that change frequently may result in degraded performance (because the cache gets trashed often).

A bit more in-depth info here:

[Application performance optimization on Android](http://blog.newmovieclip.com/2010/11/13/adobe-air-mobile-application-performance-optimization-on-android/)

[Adobe AIR - Mobile Performance – Tips & Tricks](http://www.slideshare.net/mcorlan/adobe-air-mobile-performance-tips-tricks)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Still confused about how and when to properly use the combined 'cacheAsBitmap and cacheAsBitmapMatrix' properties.

If I have a puppet character made up of bitmaps which are animated on the timeline, would I benefit if applying the 'cacheAsBitmap and cacheAsBitmapMatrix' properties to the actual puppet movie clip? or instead to each individual bitmap elements(heads, arms, legs, torso) after turning them into movie clips first?

Comment: My guess would be no. Since animation parts would presumably animate often, resulting movieclip would need to be rendered to cache each time, which would probably negate any benefits. But, individual parts that form the character might be a safer bet, especially if you include cacheAsBitmapMatrix so rotation and resize don't trigger  a cache redraw. Of course, you'll need to run some tests to be sure.

Comment: thanks. What I figured. At any rate am getting 50+ fps when targeting 60fps for a fairly complex app so am a happy camper. Have yet to see a need for dedicated Stage3D frameworks unless targeting multiple and older mobile devices.

Comment: 50fps is definitely good performance. And, frankly, if you can manage to wring out decent performance out of it, old display list still has a lot of advantages over Stage3D.